# Creating a function that returns a dictionary with eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: python, function, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm trying to create a function in Python that returns a dictionary with an eigenvector and it's corresponding eigenvalue:

This is my working code so far:

```
def eigenvectors(a):
    b = np.matrix(a)
    dicto = {}
    for i in b:
        dicto.append(b)
    return dicto

eigenvectors('1,2,3')
```

I don't think I'm going about this the right way. Basically, my parameter I'm trying to define is a matrix where no matter what matrix I put in the function, I will be able to get back the eigenvector and eigenvalue associated with it.

If anyone could help me out, I would really appreciate it. I feel like I have the concept down but I'm just having a hard time putting the function together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `numpy.linalg.eig` helps? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

If you want it exclusively as a dict you can simply use `zip`:

```
a = np.array([
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
])

def eigenvectors(a):
    values, vectors = np.linalg.eig(a)
    return dict(zip(values, vectors))

eigenvectors(a)
```

Comment: I think it does help. If I do eigenvectors(a), it does return the key and value. The only thing I'm missing is trying to get my parameter to be a matrix if you can help me out with that.

def eigenvectors(a):
    values, vectors = np.linalg.eig(a)
    return dict(zip(values, vectors))

eigenvectors([1,3,5], [3,4,5])

Comment: What do you mean by "get my parameter to be a matrix"? `a` is supposed to be a square matrix

Comment: Got it. Apologies: I missed the part where you already initialized the a to be a matrix. My bad. This solution works. Thanks!